# Using angulartics to track my hybrid application pageview

Tags: google-analytics, onsen-ui, angulartics

I add the angulartics into my hybrid application like this：

```
<script src="./js/angulartics.js"></script>
<script src="./js/angulartics-ga-cordova.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function()
    { (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)}
    ,i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-xxxx-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav buttons', 4);
</script>
```

And in the script.js like this:

```
 var module = ons.bootstrap('my-app', ['onsen','ngSanitize','ngCookies','ngStorage', 'angulartics','angulartics.google.analytics.cordova']);
```

But I also cannot track my hybrid application page view in the google analytics real time report.Anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using Angulartics google analytics not the cordova version.  You can find that here:

https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics-google-analytics

Make sure you are tracking the whole page url as well by adding this to your application config.

```
$analyticsProvider.withAutoBase(true);
```

Comment: Can you see the request being sent to google?  I use devtools in chrome to see the requests google sends out.  It'll look something like this...  https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?

Comment: You can also use the debug.analytics plugin to see what requests are being sent out.

Comment: So it's just not showing up at all in google? Have you checked Google analytics to make sure its not blocking your IP address, if you see the request being sent out then you should also be able to see it in the real time tab in GA.  You also need to run the code from the URL that you have set in ga otherwise ga will ignore it.